# flash[:error] = '<u>Error in Wells:</u><br />' + flash[:error]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

```
flash[:error] = '<u>Error in Wells:</u><br />' + flash[:error]
```

I am getting this error

```
    AbstractController::DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".): app/controllers/application_controller.rb:70:in `error'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:441:in `block (2 levels) in parse_job_xml_modern'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:115:in `each'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:115:in `block in parse_job_xml_modern'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:92:in `parse_job_xml_modern'
  app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:1017:in `block in parse_job_xml'
  app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:1012:in `each'
  app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:1012:in `parse_job_xml'
  app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:760:in `parse'


  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.
0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_source.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.
0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (5.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.
0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.
0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_web_console.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/web-console-2.0.
0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layo
ut (77.0ms)
```

Comment: Edit your question to include the controller method where the error originates.

Comment: unless well_xml_parse(upload_job_path) # We're parsing this elsewhere (for reusability)
   binding.pry
            flash[:error] = '<u>Error in Wells:</u><br />' + flash[:error]
     
     
     return(error("", upload_job_path))

Comment: here the error is coming in controler

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
flash[:error] = 'Error in Wells:' + flash[:error]
```